# Could google cloud platform vertextAI running code on backend without output?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai

The problem is my local internet connection is unstable, I could run the code through Jupyter to the interactive google cloud platform vertexAI, while it seems that there're always outputs returns back to the Jupyter interface. So when my local internet connection is interrupted, the code running is also interrupted.

Is there any methods that I could let the codes just run on the vertexAI backends? Then outputs could be written in the log file at last.

This could be a very basic question. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you running your code in the Jupyter notebook hosted by Vertex AI? What kind of code did you run?

Comment: AFAIK when a long running code is executed in the notebook hosted by Vertex AI it should continue running even if your internet connection got interrupted since it is in the cloud. I ran a code that contains timeouts inside a loop and disconnected my internet connection to test. I connected after a while and code is still running.

Comment: @RiccoD Thanks a lot for you reply. Yes, I run the code in the Jupyter notebook on VertexAI.  I also found after being interrupted for a short while, it indeed still give outputs. But my problem is my code need many hours' running, so sometimes when the interrupted time is too long, it will finnaly terminated.

Comment: I see. Do you have an estimate on how long before the code is terminated when connection is lost?

Comment: I think about 1~2 hour. But besides I want to close my pc when the code is running on the vertexAI platform, and my pc is actually no use at that time.

Comment: let me know if my answer worked for you so I can edit or delete it.

Comment: Hi @RiccoD, first I should thanks a lot for your patient reply! The methods you have provided looks helpful! But it seems that every time I could only run one scripts, right? after I run the command "nohup jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute test.ipynb &", I should also wait the compution complete then run another one. So if I want to run several commands at one time, is there any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: When `nohup` is invoked, the command runs on the background and a delegates a processID for each command. If I'm not mistaken you can run multiple commands with nohup and you can check if their processID and if they are running using command `ps ufw`. You can check these references [1] https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm, [2] https://shapeshed.com/unix-ps/

Comment: Hi @RiccoD, could I please ask why if I submit the command: nohup jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute lstm_general_model6.ipynb &, The cursor is stuck there and I can't enter the next command right after (see the updated picture)? Thanks a lot again for your patient help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to run your notebook on the background, I did the following steps:

1. Open Jupyter notebook in GCP > Vertex AI > Workbench > Open Jupyterlab
2. Open a terminal
3. Use the command below.

   ```
   nohup jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute test.ipynb &
   ```

   - `nohup` and `&` is added so that the command will run on the background
   - Output logs for the actual command will be appened to file **nohup.out**
   - Use `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute test.ipynb` to execute the notebook specified after `--execute`. `--to notebook` will create a new notebook that contains the executed notebook with its logs.
   - There other formats other than notebook to convert it. You can read thru more in [nbconvert documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

For testing I made notebook **(test.ipynb)** that has a loop that runs for 1.5 hours, that should emulate a long process.

```
import time

for x in range(1,1080):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I ran the command provided above and closed my notebook and anything related to GCP. After 1.5 hours I opened the notebook and terminal says its done.

**Terminal upon checking back after 1.5 hours:**
[image]

Content of **nohup.out**:

[image]

It created a new notebook named **"test.nbconvert.ipynb"** that contains the code from test.ipynb and its output.

Snippet of test.nbconvert.ipynb as seen below. It completed the loop up to 1080 iterations that took 1.5 hours:

[image]